# Type Parameters in `abstract class`

Tags: scala

Given:

```
scala> abstract class Foo[A] {
     |   def f: A
     | }
defined class Foo
```

, and an implementation

```
scala> class FooImpl extends Foo[Any] {
     |   def f: Any = "foo"
     | }
defined class FooImpl
```

and then an instantiation

```
scala> new FooImpl().f
res0: Any = foo
```

`res0` has type `Any`, as I'd expect since `FooImpl` uses `Any` as its type parameter to `Foo`.

And, given a second implementation:

```
scala> class FooImpl2 extends Foo[Any] {
     |   override def f= "foo"
     | }
defined class FooImpl2
```

and an instantiation and call to `f`:

```
scala> new FooImpl2().f
res1: String = foo
```

Why is `res1`'s type a `String`?

Whereas, given:

```
scala> def g[A](x: A):A = x
g: [A](x: A)A
```

I can pass `y`, an `Int`:

```
scala> val y: Int = 55
y: Int = 55
```

to `g`

```
scala> g[AnyVal](y)
res3: AnyVal = 55
```

and get back an `AnyVal`.

Finally,

```
scala> g(55)
res5: Int = 55
```

returns an `Int`, as expected.

However, I would've expected `FooImpl2#f` to have returned an `Any` given `FooImpl2`'s `extends Foo[Any]`.

Why not?

Comment: It's worth noting that this is possible in Java as well (but only since the introduction of covariant return types in Java 5), and that in both Scala and Java it results in two methods at the JVM-level: the more specific one and a synthetic method matching the implemented signature.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you override a member of an abstract class or trait, you are allowed to narrow its type to something more specific. It doesn't *appear* that way here, because you're relying on type inference for `override def f = "foo"`, but it's really `override def f: String = "foo"`.

This is legal:

```
abstract class Foo[A] {
  def f: A
}

class FooImpl2 extends Foo[Any] {
  override def f: String = "foo"
}
```

`String` still conforms to the type parameter `A = Any`, but `f` has been refined in `FooImpl2` to `String`.

Here is an example without the type parameter:

```
abstract class A { def f: Any }
class B extends A { override def f: String = "a" }
```

`g[AnyVal](y)` is a just very different example. Since you are manually supplying the type parameter of `AnyVal` to `g`, you are asking the compiler to make sure `y` is `AnyVal`, but it doesn't matter if it is some more specific type (a more specific type returned by method will always be up-cast to the return type). In `FooImpl2` you are simply changing the signature of `f`.

Answer (score 4):

When you `override` a method, you can make it return more specific type. In this line

```
override def f= "foo"
```

you didn't specify return type and it was inferred to be `String`

Answer (score 1):

A subclass can narrow the return types of the methods that it overrides.
The return type of `f` in `Foo[Any]` is `Any`. `FooImpl2` is a subtype of `Foo[Any]` and you didn't specify `f`s return type so the compiler infers that it is `String`, which is a subtype of `Any` and thus satisfies all constraints.